# Etch-a-sketch: Hover over a grid of divs to show an image... while preserving the shadows of the screen?

Tags: css, hover, shadow, mousehover

Like I've written in the title I came across this pickle: you will see in the code snippet that I made that light grey screen where the grid sits (I commented in the CSS section where you can find the grid!). The problem is that, when you hover over it, the shadows around the borders of the screen get overclassed, losing all the effects that I wanted to give.

So my question is: how can I over over the screen without losing the shadow on its border both in the moment that you hover over it but also when the background shows up?
Long story short, I'd like my screen shadows to always be present!

Thank you!

P.S. I don't understand why the knobs look different in the snippet. In the browser they look like I wanted them to be!

```js
function makeGrid(a, b) {
    const container = document.querySelector('#screen');
    let divRow = undefined;

    for (i = 0; a > i; i++) {
        divRow = document.createElement('div')
        container.appendChild(divRow);
    }

    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div');
    let divColumn = undefined;

    containers.forEach(function (div) {
        for (i = 0; b > i; i++) {
            divColumn = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(divColumn)
        }
    })
}
makeGrid(30, 50);
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    border: solid 2px;
}

#box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 542px;
    width: 680px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 20px 20px;

    background-color:rgb(179, 2, 2);

}

#shell {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 400px;
    width: 670px;
    border-radius: 26px 26px 0px 0px;

    background-color: rgb(220, 0, 0);
}

#screen-border {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 320px;
    width: 520px;
    border-top: solid 5px rgb(189, 2, 2);
    border-right: solid 2px white;
    border-left: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: inset 1.5px 0px white,
                inset 0px -8px 10px rgb(220, 0, 0),
                inset -1.5px 0px white;

    background-color: rgb(179, 2, 2);
}

#screen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    border-top: solid 0.1px #292828;
    border-right: solid 0.1px rgb(189, 2, 2);
    border-left: solid 0.1px rgb(189, 2, 2);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgb(179, 2, 2),
                inset 0px 10px 10px -8px rgb(18, 18, 18),
                inset -8px 0px 10px -4px #707070,
                inset 8px 0px 10px -4px #707070;

    background-color: #cdcdcd
}

#screen div {                /*THESE ARE THE ROWS...*/
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

#screen div div {             /*...AND THESE ARE THE LITTLE SQUARES INSIDE THE ROWS!!*/
    width: 100%;
    /*border: solid 1px;      <------ UNLOCK US TO SHOW THE GRID!!!
    box-sizing: border-box;*/
}

#screen div div:hover {  /* <------ Silly example to explain my point*/
background-color: pink;
}


#knobs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 130px;
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 18px 18px;

    background-color:rgb(220, 0, 0);
}


#central-left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: rgb(255, 240, 240);
    
}
#central-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-right: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: rgb(255, 240, 240);
}


#outer-left, #outer-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 102px;
    width: 102px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #382929;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #bebebe;
}
#outer-left {
    margin-left: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                8px -1px 20px #382929;
}
#outer-right {
    margin-right: 20px; 
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                -8px -1px 20px #382929;

}


#inner-left, #inner-right {
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: white;
}
#inner-left {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 15px 12px rgb(225, 225, 225),
                5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac,;
                

}
#inner-right {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset -3px 3px 15px 12px rgb(225, 225, 225),
                -5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac,;
                 

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="box">

            <div id="shell">

                <div id="screen-border">
                    <div id="screen"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="knobs">

                <div id="outer-left">
                    <div id="central-left">
                        <div id="inner-left"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="outer-right">
                    <div id="central-right">
                        <div id="inner-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is simply that the `<div>` containing your inner shadow is underneath the other elements. And so they are effectively covering up your inner shadow at times.

So the solution would be to place your shadows on an element that is over everything else. However, this will cause issues like being unable to click on any elements underneath the shadows. Thankfully, there is a CSS property called `pointer-events` which can be set to **none** to prevent the mouse/cursor from interacting with that element.

From here, I just placed a new `<span>` element (only to avoid conflict with CSS applied to all child `<div>` elements) with an absolute position that is the full width and height of its parent and gave this `<span>` element your inner shadow.

```js
function makeGrid(a, b) {
    const container = document.querySelector('#screen');
    let divRow = undefined;

    for (i = 0; a > i; i++) {
        divRow = document.createElement('div')
        container.appendChild(divRow);
    }

    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div');
    let divColumn = undefined;

    containers.forEach(function (div) {
        for (i = 0; b > i; i++) {
            divColumn = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(divColumn)
        }
    })
}
makeGrid(30, 50);
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    border: solid 2px;
}

#box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 542px;
    width: 680px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 20px 20px;

    background-color:rgb(179, 2, 2);

}

#shell {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 400px;
    width: 670px;
    border-radius: 26px 26px 0px 0px;

    background-color: rgb(220, 0, 0);
}

#screen-border {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 320px;
    width: 520px;
    border-top: solid 5px rgb(189, 2, 2);
    border-right: solid 2px white;
    border-left: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: inset 1.5px 0px white,
                inset 0px -8px 10px rgb(220, 0, 0),
                inset -1.5px 0px white;

    background-color: rgb(179, 2, 2);
}

#screen {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    border-top: solid 0.1px #292828;
    border-right: solid 0.1px rgb(189, 2, 2);
    border-left: solid 0.1px rgb(189, 2, 2);
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
  position: relative;
}
#screenInner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgb(179, 2, 2),
    inset 0px 10px 10px -8px rgb(18, 18, 18),
    inset -8px 0px 10px -4px #707070,
    inset 8px 0px 10px -4px #707070;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#screen div {                /*THESE ARE THE ROWS...*/
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

#screen div div {             /*...AND THESE ARE THE LITTLE SQUARES INSIDE THE ROWS!!*/
    width: 100%;
    /*border: solid 1px #AAA;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset
}

#screen div div:hover {  /* <------ Silly example to explain my point*/
background-color: pink;
}


#knobs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 130px;
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 18px 18px;

    background-color:rgb(220, 0, 0);
}


#central-left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: rgb(255, 240, 240);
    
}
#central-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-right: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: rgb(255, 240, 240);
}


#outer-left, #outer-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 102px;
    width: 102px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #382929;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #bebebe;
}
#outer-left {
    margin-left: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                8px -1px 20px #382929;
}
#outer-right {
    margin-right: 20px; 
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                -8px -1px 20px #382929;

}


#inner-left, #inner-right {
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: white;
}
#inner-left {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 15px 12px rgb(225, 225, 225),
                5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac,;
                

}
#inner-right {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset -3px 3px 15px 12px rgb(225, 225, 225),
                -5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac,;
                 

}
```

```html
<div id="container">

        <div id="box">

            <div id="shell">

                <div id="screen-border">
                    <div id="screen">
                      <span id="screenInner"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="knobs">

                <div id="outer-left">
                    <div id="central-left">
                        <div id="inner-left"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="outer-right">
                    <div id="central-right">
                        <div id="inner-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I also swapped out your 'gridline' `border` property with an inner `box-shadow` instead. I find this to be a prettier approach to adding grid-like borders because it only applies a *border* on 2 of the 4 sides (yes you can do this with the `border-top` etc, but it adds more CSS).

Comment: Hi! I really enjoyed the idea of the `box-shadow` for the grid! 
Ok, regarding the other stuff, maybe I'm missing some theoretic concepts about DOM relationship. How is it that the `<span>` is now outer than the div squares? Isn't it a sibling of the div rows and so still underneath/before the div squares? Basically, I think I didn't get the relationship between what happened with the adding of the `<span>` and the `pointer-events`!

Comment: The `<div>` with the id `screen` applies CSS to all child `<div>` elements. Because of this, I opted to use `<span>` instead of `<div>`, but ultimately you just need 1 element inside of your `screen` element. From there, setting `position: absolute;` on the child and `position: relative;` on the parent allows the child `<span>` to overlay the entire parent `<div>`. Then you can apply the shadow. But because it overlays the parent, you need `pointer-events: none;` to prevent the child `<span>` from blocking the other elements.

Comment: Allright! There is also the `postion` property to use, I missed that. I was reading that it basically alters the normal hierarchy of the elements. I also saw that you used the `user-select` property: is it necessary? Because I saw that it worked also without it

Comment: The `user-select` property is not necessary for this. It just disables the ability to highlight anything in an element, but because `pointer-events` is set to **none** it basically does the same thing.